# Dagger2 dependecies reference to applicationComponent is not providing object to inject

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I was following some examples to work on dagger2. Here I was using dependencies on HomeFragmentComponent to provide reference of context from another scope but its not working.

ContextModule

```
    @Module
    public class ContextModule {
          private final Context context;

          public ContextModule(Context context) {
              this.context = context;
          }

         @Provides
         @ShikshyaScope
         public Context context(){
              return context;
         }
    }
```

Network Module :

```
@Module(includes = ContextModule.class)
public class NetworkModule {

      @Provides
      @ShikshyaScope
      public File file(Context context){
           File cacheFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"okhttp_cache");
           cacheFile.mkdirs();
           return cacheFile;
 }
```

ShikshyaApplicationComponent:

```
  @ShikshyaScope
  @Component(modules = {NetworkModule.class, PicassoModule.class, StorageModule.class})
  public interface ShikshyaApplicationComponent {
       void injectShikshyaApplication(ShikshyaBusApplication shikshyaBusApplication);
   }
```

Home Fragment Module :

```
@Module
public class HomeFragmentModule {

public final HomeFragment homeFragment;

public HomeFragmentModule(HomeFragment homeFragment) {
    this.homeFragment = homeFragment;
}

@Provides
@HomeFragmentScope
public HomeFragment homeFragment(){
    return homeFragment;
}

@Provides
@HomeFragmentScope
public HomeFragmentView homeFragmentView(HomeFragment homeFragment){
    return (HomeFragmentView)homeFragment;
}
@Provides
@HomeFragmentScope
public HomeFragmentPresenter homeFragmentPresenter(HomeFragmentView homeFragmentView,MetaDatabaseRepo metaDatabaseRepo){
    return new HomeFragmentPresenter(homeFragmentView,metaDatabaseRepo);
}


@Provides
@HomeFragmentScope
public DatabaseHelper databaseHelper(Context context){
    return OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context,DatabaseHelper.class);
}

}
```

HomeFragmentComponent :

```
    @HomeFragmentScope
    @Component(modules = HomeFragmentModule.class,dependencies =ShikshyaApplicationComponent.class)
     public interface HomeFragmentComponent {

     void injectHomeFragment(HomeFragment homeFragment);
     }
```

Now I get error as

```
error: android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
android.content.Context is injected at com.bihani.shikshyabus.di.module.HomeFragmentModule.databaseHelper(context)
```

com.bihani.shikshyabus.database.DatabaseHelper is injected at

Comment: How are you providing context to ContextModule?

Comment: @AlexTa ShikshyaApplicationComponent component = DaggerShikshyaApplicationComponent.builder()
                .contextModule(new ContextModule(this))
                .build();       But before it, I couldn't build the project so I think solving the above problem is required first to get DaggerObject

Answer (score 0):

You should include `ContextModule` as `HomeFragmentModule` dependency so Dagger2 be able to provide `context` to `DatabaseHelper`

```
@Module(includes = ContextModule.class)
public class HomeFragmentModule {
    // Your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Yes I had tried that earlier then it gives me following error                    error: com.bihani.shikshyabus.ui.home.homeFragment.HomeFragmentComponent scoped with 
         com.bihani.shikshyabus.di.scope.HomeFragmentScope may not reference bindings with different scopes:
         Provides com.bihani.shikshyabus.di.scope.ShikshyaScope android.content.Context com.bihani.shikshyabus.di.module.ContextModule.context()
'